# R cli progress bar within purrr::map

Tags: r, dictionary, command-line-interface, progress-bar, purrr

I need to present a progress bar that show the progress of a `purrr::pmap`.
I use the `cli` package for user facing information generally, and there is a progress bar in there that seems proficient. However, I cannot get access to a created progress bar inside of another function.

```
library(cli)
library(purrr)

a <- 1:1000
p <- cli::cli_progress_bar(total = length(a))
te <- function(x){
  cli::cli_progress_update(id=p)
  return(1/x)
}

cli_progress_done(id=p)

a |> purrr::map(te)
```

It seems that the `id` argument is not used? Is there a way to access the progress bar inside of the inner function so that I can update the progress?

Thanks!

Fredrik

Comment: Check the value of `nrow(a)`. I think you meant `length(a)`

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed it, but the original problem is still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the  [`.progress`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/progress_bars.html) argument (its based on `cli`) in `purrr::map()`:

```
a <- 1:1000
map(a, function(x){Sys.sleep(1/100); (1/x)}, .progress = list(
  type = "iterator", 
  format = "Calculating {cli::pb_bar} {cli::pb_percent}",
  clear = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! I was on purrr 0.35 and was unaware of the new progress bar structure.